# Gitlab runner locally as dind - Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/ . Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am on `Mac` and using `docker-desktop` for `docker` set up. I am trying out my gitlab pipeline locally. Below is my `.gitlab.ci.yaml` .

```
default:
  image: docker:19.03

variables:
  # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/
  # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

before_script:
    - apk update
    - apk add gcc libc-dev libffi-dev librdkafka-dev git
    - apk add --update --no-cache python3 python3-dev nodejs npm curl && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
    - npm install -g aws-cdk
    - python3 -m ensurepip
    - pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry update
    - poetry install
    - source `poetry env info --path`/bin/activate

cdk deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:19.03
  services:
   - name: docker:dind # Docker-in-Docker
     alias: dockerdaemon
  script:
    - poetry run cdk deploy --require-approval never
```

Now I am running into issue like `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/. Is the docker daemon running?` .

I have updated my `resolv.conf` with `nameserver 8.8.8.8` as suggested by google.